# php ternary shorthand for use in template

Tags: php, templates, ternary

I'm building my first application with Kohana, and using a basic templating system within that. In my templates I want to echo variables for the various contents of the page, but only if each variable is set, and I want to keep the code in the templates as short as possible, so something like this:

```
<?=$foo?>
```

works fine if the variable is set, but if it's not I get a notice. So I thought a ternary operator would do the trick nicely:

```
<?=$foo?:''?>
```

according to the PHP manual, from 5.3 it's ok to leave out the middle part and the above should output nothing if the variable isn't set, but I still get an error notice."Notice: Undefined variable: foo in /"

I can get the desired result with a slight alteration to suppress the notice:

```
<?=@$foo?:''?>
```

but I know that's generally not beset practice and would like a better solution if possible, while still keeping the code to a minimum in the template files.

the following works, but it's not as concise (mainly because my actual variables can be quite long):

```
<?=isset($foo)?$foo:'';?>
```

am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ternary operation is not meant to replace checking with `isset()` - it needs it's variable defined or else you get a notice.

Template engines usually offer a way to use a default value instead, but they also do not use pure PHP code. You you are out of luck here: Either suppress the notice, or use the longer code variant. Or ensure that every variable is set, which enables you to consider any notice an error.

Comment: ok thanks, I guess I misunderstood the following then: "Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise." I'm using pure php in my templates so I guess in this case the cleanest option is to suppress the errors. thanks for your input.

Comment: To avoid notices, you'd have to use `isset($var)?:$default`, but that wouldn't return the content of `$var`, but the result of `isset($var)`, which is `true` - and that does not really work. `isset($var)?$var:$default` is needed.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid notices for undefined variables, you can create custom function that takes first parameter by reference

```
function tplvar(&$value, $default = '') {
    return ($value !== null) ? $value : $default;
}

<?=tplvar($foo, 'bar');?>
```

Uninitialized variables passed by reference will be seen as `null`s.